# How do you add a string to a deque without breaking the string up into characters?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a deque of strings, but when I add a string to the deque it always breaks the string up into individual characters. Here is my code so far:

```
from collections import deque

my_string = "test"
my_queue = deque(my_string)

print my_queue
```

The output I get is:

```
deque(['t', 'e', 's', 't'])
```

I would like the output to be:

```
deque(['test'])
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The deque constructor takes an iterable as a parameter, if you just give the string to it, it will interpret it as a sequence of characters.

In order to do what you want you should wrap your string into a list:

```
your_string = 'string'
wrap_list = [your_string]
#Now create the deque
d = deque(wrap_list)
```

Of course you can do everything in one step:

```
your_string = 'string'
d = deque([your_string])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
deque([my_string])
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do it with another variable, instead of putting the string directly into the deque constructor?

Answer (score 1):

deque takes in a list of items. A string is a list of characters, so the deque breaks the string in to characters. If you want to add whole strings at a time, you have to add the string into an array
`['test1', 'test2', 'etc']`
To answer your question: you need to use `deque(['test'])`